# How to get the name of the item that is being checked by the user in next activity in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm working on an android app where user will select the food quantity and move to the checkout screen to purchase that similar to what `foodpanda`, `swiggy` does.

But I'm unable to fetch the content of the item being selected using the quantity. It is showing the package name instead of the item name.

Code -

```
public class Food implements Parcelable,Serializable {
    String Foodname;
    int CartQuantity = 0;
    double FoodPrice;

    public Food(String Foodname, int cartQuantity, double FoodPrice) {
        this.Foodname = Foodname;
        this.CartQuantity = cartQuantity;
        this.FoodPrice = FoodPrice;
    }

    protected Food(Parcel in) {
        Foodname = in.readString();
        CartQuantity = in.readInt();
        FoodPrice = in.readDouble();
    }

    public static final Creator<Food> CREATOR = new Creator<Food>() {
        @Override
        public Food createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Food(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Food[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Food[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(this.Foodname);
            dest.writeInt(this.CartQuantity);
            dest.writeDouble(this.FoodPrice);
    }
}
```

ListAdapter.class -

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Food> listproducts;
    private Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Food> listproducts){
        this.context=context;
        this.listproducts=listproducts;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listproducts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Food getItem(int position) {
        return listproducts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            listViewHolder.foodName = row.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
            listViewHolder.foodPrice = row.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem1);
            listViewHolder.cartQuantity = row.findViewById(R.id.integer_number);
            listViewHolder.increment = row.findViewById(R.id.increase);
            listViewHolder.decrement = row.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
            row.setTag(listViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            row=convertView;
            listViewHolder= (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Food food=getItem(position);

        listViewHolder.foodName.setText(food.Foodname);
        listViewHolder.foodPrice.setText(food.FoodPrice+" $");
        listViewHolder.cartQuantity.setText(food.CartQuantity+"");
        listViewHolder.increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                updateQuantity(position,listViewHolder.cartQuantity,1);
            }
        });
        //listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText("0");
        listViewHolder.decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateQuantity(position,listViewHolder.cartQuantity,-1);

            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    private void updateQuantity(int position, TextView edTextQuantity, int value) {

        Food food = getItem(position);
        if(value > 0&&food.CartQuantity<10)
        {
            food.CartQuantity = food.CartQuantity + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(food.CartQuantity > 0)
            {
                food.CartQuantity = food.CartQuantity - 1;
            }

        }
        edTextQuantity.setText(food.CartQuantity+"");
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried and this is what I'm getting from this code.

Activity where the user will select the items to order

[image]

Activity which displays the selected items by the user

[image: image2]

Instead of showing the item name, price and quantity, it is displaying the package name.
How can I get the required values by changing the code?

Comment: Please share your code with me, so i will do changes on it.

Comment: @ankitpatidar You mean the complete project?

Comment: Yes, if you can?

Comment: Sure @ankitpatidar

Comment: @ankitpatidar https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wR98ylXVGU5MdKcxy-ilzO3UnNUqkQiE?usp=sharing Code is here.

Comment: @ankitpatidar U got the code?

Comment: Yes yes..I will do that. And get back to you

Comment: Ok. Waiting! @ankitpatidar

Comment: @ankitpatidar DId u get anything?

Comment: I solved that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes on your code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

static int count=0;
private Context _context;

HashMap<String,Food> selectedItems;

public List<String> listDataHeader; // header titles

// child data in format of header title, child title
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Food>> _listDataChild;

CheckOutItems checkOutItems;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, ArrayList<Food>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    selectedItems = new HashMap<>();

    checkOutItems = (CheckOutItems)context;

}

@Override
public Food getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

Button button;
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        listViewHolder.foodName = row.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        listViewHolder.foodPrice = row.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem1);
        listViewHolder.cartQuantity = row.findViewById(R.id.integer_number);
        listViewHolder.increment = row.findViewById(R.id.increase);
        listViewHolder.decrement = row.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
        listViewHolder.addButton = row.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        row.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        row=convertView;
        listViewHolder= (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    final Food food=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

    listViewHolder.foodName.setText(food.Foodname);
    listViewHolder.foodPrice.setText(food.FoodPrice+" $");
    listViewHolder.cartQuantity.setText(food.CartQuantity+"");
    listViewHolder.increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            updateQuantity(groupPosition,childPosition,listViewHolder.cartQuantity,1);
        }
    });
    //listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText("0");
    listViewHolder.decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateQuantity(groupPosition,childPosition,listViewHolder.cartQuantity,-1);

        }
    });

    listViewHolder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedItems.put(food.Foodname,food);
            checkOutItems.sendItems(selectedItems);
        }
    });

    return row;
}

private void updateQuantity(int group,int position, TextView edTextQuantity, int value) {

    Food food = getChild(group,position);
    if(value > 0&&food.CartQuantity<10)
    {
        food.CartQuantity = food.CartQuantity + 1;
        count++;


    }
    else
    {
        if(food.CartQuantity > 0)
        {
            food.CartQuantity = food.CartQuantity - 1;
            count--;

        }

    }
    edTextQuantity.setText(food.CartQuantity+"");
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return _listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

interface CheckOutItems
{
    public void sendItems(HashMap<String,Food> selectedItems);
}
 }
```

And here is link of Google Drive for the whole project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15utf5kuJJHUXDR1bOLeb7DAIDJ54RwOW

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question is you want to get the products 
selected in food adapter in your next activity.

Firstly create a method in your adapter:

```
public ArrayList<Food> getSelectedProducts(){
   ArrayList<Food> selected = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Food food:listProducts){
      if(food.getCartQuantity() > 0){
        selected.add(food);
       }
   }
     return selected; 
 }
```

now get the selected items in current activity:

```
ArrayList<Food> products = adapter.getSelectedProducts();
```

then put the products in an intent your are using to navigate to the next activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your intent");
intent.putExtra("data", (Serializable)products);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your next activity get selected items as:

```
ArrayList<Food> selectedProducts = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the object reference to setText . Something like

Food f = getFood(); //Did some logic

//Setting text like below.

textView.setText(f);//Wrong

Try using something like this.

textView.setText(f.FoodName));// Get Proper attribute from object to show the exact name.